# Convert a value to 4 decimal place in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm calculating an hourlyrate which depends on a column value from a different table.

Suppose I have `hourlyrate` from `table1` and `rates` from table2. If `rates = 4` in `table2` where 4 is representing 4 decimal place, then based on a calculation, the hourlyrate should give value to 4 decimal place.

Here is my calculation:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(
 CASE WHEN table2.rates ='4' 
      THEN table1.hourlyrate 
      ELSE table1.hourlyrate END as decimal(18,4)))
```

Should i divide the value to get 4dp? Any advice please?

Comment: Procedural code (like stored procedures) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What if rates=2? will it need only 2 decimal places

Comment: The part `THEN table1.hourlyrate ELSE table1.hourlyrate END` does not make any sense.

Comment: `the hourlyrate should give value to 4 decimal place.` - give an example, it is incomprehensible like this. Provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: i have hourlyrate = 477.9933 which is showing up as 477.99  the correct value for hourlyrate should be 477.9933 if rate is set to 4dp or 2 dp

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should always provide a length for all `varchar` or `nvarchar` variables/parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option if 2012+ is using Format()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (HourlyRate varchar(50),Rate varchar(10)) 
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('125   ','4')
,('85.25' ,'2')
,('75.1255' ,'')
,('9.33333333' ,'6')


Select format(convert(float,HourlyRate),'0.'+left('0000000',Rate))
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
125.0000
85.25
75
9.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion should be after the `then` instead of around the whole `case` expression.

```
select 
    ...
  , HourlyRate = case when table2.rates in ('2','4')
          then convert(varchar(32),convert(decimal(18,4),table1.hourlyrate))
      else table1.hourlyrate
      end
    )
from ...
```

---

In SQL Server 2012+, you could use [**`try_convert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) instead of `convert()` to return `null` values instead of an error if the conversion fails.

```
select 
    ...
  , HourlyRate = case when table2.rates in ('2','4')
          then convert(varchar(32),try_convert(decimal(18,4),table1.hourlyrate))
      else table1.hourlyrate
      end
    )
from ...
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KYXEV38143

returns:

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| rates | hourlyrate | HourlyRate |
+-------+------------+------------+
|     1 | 1.23456789 | 1.23456789 |
|     2 | 1.23456789 | 1.2346     |
|     2 |            | NULL       |
|     3 | 1.23456789 | 1.23456789 |
|     4 | 1.23456789 | 1.2346     |
|     4 | 1          | 1.0000     |
|     4 | N/A        | NULL       |
+-------+------------+------------+
```